# unexpected token < when deploying to an iis server using MEAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN and i just got a few features built in the application, but now i am trying to deploy on an iis server. i obtain all the paths, but nothing is been display due to the following error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  jquery.js:1`

when i click to see the error the chrome dev tool shows me the index file shown below and points to the first line. Anyone knows how i can fix the error above?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/toastr/toastr.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/angular-material/angular-material.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.css" />

  <title>My App</title>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="fullStackScratch">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
  <footer>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <p> &copy; Testing Footer</p>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular-material/angular-material.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular-aria/angular-aria.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/main/MainCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="app/account/login.controller.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I just added the following files

**route.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function (app){
  app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('../../public/app/' + req.params[0]);
  });

app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user) {
    if(!user){
    res.send({success:false})
  }
  req.logIn(user, function(err){
    if(err){
      return next(err);
    }
    res.send({success:true, user:user})
  })
});
auth(req, res, next);
});

  app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
  });
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();
var config = require('./server/config/config.js') [env];

require('./server/config/express.js')(app, config);
require('./server/config/mongoose.js')(config);

var users = mongoose.model('users');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    users.findOne({username: username}).exec(function (err, user) {
     if(user){
        return done(null, user);
     }else {
        return done(null, false);
     }
    })
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  if(user){
    done(null, user._id);
 }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  users.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function(err, user){
    if(user){
      return done(null, user);
    }else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  })
})

require('./server/config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + config.port + '...');
```

**express.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(app, config){
  function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
  }

  app.set('views', config.rootPath + '/server/views');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(bodyParser());
  app.use(session({secret: 'full stack from scratch'}));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
      src: config.rootPath + '/public',
      compile: compile
    }
  ));
  app.use(express.static(config.rootPath + '/public'));
  }
```

Comment: In your development tools, look at what the downloaded `jquery.js` contains; most likely an HTML error page or one of our routes as @Paul said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there's something in how your application is routing, that it's trying to serve your HTML file instead of the jquery one. So when the page loads the first HTML file, and then it calls for the jquery file the browser vomits on not being able to parse the second HTML file (which it thinks is a javascript file).

Comment: if i understand correctly. i need to make the browser read a js file and not read it as a html right? and that should be done in my **route.js** file correct? i added some extra codes

Comment: Not exactly.  What I'm saying is that something in how you're declaring your routes (which seems to be happening in several places, not just routes.js) is causing the server to match the jquery route for one of your other routes (probably your index route, from what you have in that auth() function, but I'm not sure)